# Redirect without HTTP doesnt work

Tags: url, redirect, installation, mediawiki

I have installed MediaWiki, and a link dissapears that redirects me to 'http://wiki.website.com/mw-config/index.php'. The problem is: I go to 'http://mw-config/index.php'. How is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: re-asked at [MediaWiki cannot get path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696756/mediawiki-cannot-get-path) with somewhat more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the link is being written out as `href="//mw-config/index.php"` which will cause the behaviour you are seeing. The question of why is probably something to do with your configuration (something to do with a base path, if this is the cause), but it's hard to say exactly what without knowing more.

Comment: Thanks, I have paste the same code in my localhost. If i look to the source code for the link **localhost** displays: `Please <a href="/wiki.website.com/mw-config/index.php"> set up the wiki</a> first.` and my **live domain** displays: `Please <a href="\/mw-config/index.php"> set up the wiki</a> first.` Very strange. How is that possible?