# MediaWiki cannot get path

Tags: installation, mediawiki

My MediaWiki cannot get the path of my live web server. Here is the code:

```
$script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$path = pathinfo( $script, PATHINFO_DIRNAME ) . '/';
$path = str_replace( '//', '/', $path );
$ext = pathinfo( $script, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

echo "Please <a href=\"" . htmlspecialchars( $path ) . "mw-config/index." . htmlspecialchars( $ext ) . "\">enter</a>";
```

The localhostwebserver displays the echo as: `Please <a href=wiki.website.com/mw-config/index.php\">enter</a>`,

but the live server displays the echo as `Please <a href=\/mw-config/index.php\">enter</a>`

How is that possible? Need help!

Comment: Please take time to explain what you are trying to do, and what you would have expected to happen. It is hard to figure out from your question what you perceive here as a problem.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that is suppose to be php in the code block?

Comment: What's wrong with that? It echoes a valid path - it doesn't need to be a full URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the url of the current page in php, I can recommend [this](http://dev.kanngard.net/Permalinks/ID_20050507183447.html) script. I have used it successfully for years.